# Create a virtual environment with python version 2.7 with existing version as 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I want to create a virtual environment with python version 2.7 on windows, however, after installing virtualenv and running `python 2.7 -m venv project`
I am receiving an error `RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='2.7'`
I have downloaded the 2.7 version of python as well, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `python -m venv project`?

Comment: Have you checked that python is in your $PATH?

Comment: @arsho where to specify the version when using `python -m venv project`

Comment: In command prompt / terminal write: `python --version` to see what python version is default in your system.

Comment: @arsho 3.7.6 is the default version

Comment: Can you please check if you can see the python 2 version using: `py -2 -V` or `python2 -V`?

Comment: @arsho it opens the interpreter, if that's what you are asking

Comment: No, I want to see if you can access `python2` from command prompt. Please paste the output of `python2 --version` from command prompt.

Comment: `'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` But I have `C:\Python27` in my environment variables, which was added by default upon installing

Comment: if `py -2` works, then it is not important, that python2 is in the search path

just do `py -2 <scriptname>` instead of `python2 <scriptname>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`venv` is a package that was only introduced from python 3.3 and above.
( https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html )
I never used it.

You might use virtualenv, that exists also for python 2.7. but must be installed with following command (but you did this probably already)

```
py -2.7 -m pip install virtualenv
```

You then type

`py -2.7 -m virtualenv project_dir`

if none of above works, then please type
`py -2.7 -m pip freeze` and post the output.

You can also type

```
py -2.7 -c "import sys ; print(sys.executable, sys.version_info)"
```

To see what python 2.7 version you have exactly installed.

**The difference between `py.exe` and `python.exe`:**

On windows `py.exe` is the python launcher, that tries to keep track of all installed python versions and of potentially activated virtualenvs and launches the one you want.

`python` will try to find the `python` executable in the search path.
and it would yield the first python in the path.

`py` is the windows python launcher which will locate the python executables with help of environment variables and the registry and which allows with the `-version` (e.g. `-2.7`) switch to select which version of python you want to call.

( Documentation for the python launcher on windows:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-the-command-line )

Comment: after running this command, I am getting `can't open file '2.7': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"`

Comment: I don't have a windows PC at hand. I think I just forgot the `-` before the `2.7`
Please retry.

Meanwhile I try to find online documentation for the python launcher to be sure this is the right syntax

Comment: elaborated on my answer. Please tell me if it still doesn't work

Comment: even though I have virtualenv installed, it is still showing me `No module named venv`, I tried with virtualenv as well but still got the same error

Comment: I am so sorry. Did not even see it before. `venv` and `virtualenv` are two distinct modules.
`venv` was only introduced from python 3.3 and above.

For python 2.7. you can use `virtualenv` .
Perhaps you can use `venv` from your python 3 version to create a virtualenv for python 2.7, but I don't think so. First quick searches don't indicate this